# Can the solvent fraction of a sol-gel process containing tetraethyl orthosilicate (TEOS) be analyzed by GCMS?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Can the solvent fraction of a sol-gel process containing tetraethyl orthosilicate (TEOS) be analyzed by GCMS? I am worried that the easy polymerization of TEOS to form silica (SiO2) will ruin the GCMS system.

Comment: See the conditions and detector in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021967307015385